# wrong answer in a codechef code

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I have a doubt in the following [problem](http://www.codechef.com/BTCD2014/problems/BTCD14B). Here is the [answer](http://ideone.com/erENot). When I count the number of ways in this manner, I am getting repetitions, i.e; for example 8 can be written as 2 + 3 + 3, 3 + 5, 8 + 0, 2 + 2 + 2 + 2. My code is counting 2 + 3 + 3 twice. How do I eliminate that? Can anybody tell me how to do this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<utility>
#define PB push_back
#define MP make_pair
#define LL long long int
#define M 1000000007
using namespace std;

LL ways[100001][30];
int fib[25]={1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393};

void solve()
{
    int i,j,d,k,f;
    for(j=0;j<30;j++)
    {
        ways[0][j] = 0;
        ways[1][j] = 1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<24;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<25;j++)
        {
            if(fib[i] != fib[j])
            ways[fib[i]][j]=1;
        }
    }

    ways[1][0] = 0;
    for(f=0;f<25;f++)
    {
        k = fib[f];
        for(i=2;i<=100000;i++)
        {
            //if(binary_search(fib,fib+26,i))
            {
                for(j=0;j<25;j++)
                {

                    if(fib[j] > i/2)
                    break;
                    if(fib[j] == k )
                    continue;
                    ways[i][f] = ways[i][f] + ways[i-fib[j]][f];
                    //if(i == fib[j])
                    //ways[i][f]++;
                    if(i == 8)
                    cout<<i<<" "<<f<<" "<<fib[j]<<" "<<ways[i][f]<<endl;

                    //cout<<i<<" "<<k<<" "<<fib[j]<<" "<<ways[i][f]<<endl;
                    //system("pause");
                    ways[i][f] %= M;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int t,i,j,k,n;
    solve();
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n>>k;
        for(i=0;i<25;i++)
        {
            if(fib[i] == k)
            {
                cout<<ways[n][i]<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        //cout<<ways[n][k]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to come up with a different algorithm that doesn't come across the same partitition more than once.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thanks, Captain Obvious...

Comment: The whole point of the challenge is for you to work out such an algorithm, surely you aren't just asking for someone to do it for you?

Comment: Please put the problem statement and answer in the question itself so as to eliminate the need to click on external resources to understand your post (which doesn't really conform to [so] guidelines).

Comment: @MattMcNabb I am a novice in dynamic programming. So I want to know how we overcome this problem.

Comment: Now I got some idea. We can go with a 2 state dp. no of ways of forming ith fibonacci number using j as a maximum number. I' m working in this direction.